# intervals and delays with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a Simon says game, and right now I'm stuck at the part where I want to light the buttons that the user has to click. I'm doing it with a "for" to analyze every part of array where I store the sequence, then the array should go to every round and light the button, like this; on and on. But for some reason the "for" changing the background of every div that has pass in the array at the same time, even though I'm using a item interval to stop at ever button.

Here's the codepen I'm working with:

https://codepen.io/argestis/pen/gLraBq?editors=0011

```js
function litSequence() {
  for (var i = 0; i < game.count.length; i++) {
    if (game.count[i] === 1) {
      game.blue.css("background-color", "cyan");
      setTimeout(function() {
        game.blue.css("background-color", "blue");
      }, 1500);

    } else if (game.count[i] === 2) {
      game.red.css("background-color", "pink");
      setTimeout(function() {
        game.red.css("background-color", "red");
      }, 1500);

    } else if (game.count[i] === 3) {
      game.green.css("background-color", " #4dff4d");
      setTimeout(function() {
        game.green.css("background-color", "green");
      }, 1500);

    } else if (game.count[i] === 4) {
      game.yellow.css("background-color", "orange");
      setTimeout(function() {
        game.yellow.css("background-color", "yellow");
      }, 1500);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: It looks like your codepen is loading many jQueries AFTER the bootstrap JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` does not -stop- your logic.  You can think of it as creating a parallel point of logic operation.  Your logic will continue to run on and only after that time has pass will the logic in the timeout execute.  Since js runs very fast it will most likely be the case that all your setTimeout within the loops fire all relatively close together to appear simultaneous.

Comment: Is there any way I could stop the loop so It can fire one by one at a slower pace?

Comment: Instead of trying to stop the logic flow, consider dynamically assigning the delay time to grow so they happen in the order you expect.  Or maybe it would be as simple as changing to your delay times to be `(game.count[i] * 1500)`